# Show us past community events from newest to oldest

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, sorting, community-events

When viewing past community events at `/admin/community-events?tab=past` (as often happens to copy one for modification and reuse) the list shows up in oldest to newest order.

This is not helpful since I'm not usually looking for random things from 5 years ago, but rather something more recent.

I don't see any way to switch the ordering back and forth, and I don't think that is such a useful feature anyway, but the default should be most recent events first, unlike the current implementation.